# Retrieving Parents and Children - Self Referencing Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, self-reference

Noob here. I would say I can see the peak of the curve but I still have a ways to go.

I have an entity (tblxchangecategories) referencing a categories table:

[image]

This is related to an entity (tblxchangecategory_hier) referencing a category hierarchy table:

[image]

The relationship is self-referencing.

There are 6 major categories that are the parents and the remaining categories (36) are all children.

This is how I've defined their relationship in the entity file (tblxchangecategories):

```
/**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="TblXchangecategories", mappedBy="children")
     **/
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity"TblXchangecategories", inversedBy="parent")
     * @JoinTable(name="tbl_xchangecategory_hier",
     *      joinColumns={@joinColumn(name="hier_parent", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="hier_child", referencedColumnName="id")}
     */
    private $children;
```

And in the other entitiy file (tblxchangecategory_hier):

```
/**
     * @var \WorkoutExchange\WXCoreBundle\Entity\TblXchangecategories
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="WorkoutExchange\WXCoreBundle\Entity\TblXchangecategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hier_parent", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $hierParent;

    /**
     * @var \WorkoutExchange\WXCoreBundle\Entity\TblXchangecategories
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WorkoutExchange\WXCoreBundle\Entity\TblXchangecategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hier_child", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $hierChild;
```

Using the following code I'm able to retrieve all of the categories in a flattened array (no relationships):

```
$categories = $em->getRepository('WorkoutExchangeWXCoreBundle:TblXchangecategories')->findAll();
```

I can set up the view, so that's no problem, it's getting the data out of the database that's causing me troubles.

I've seen references to the `->getChildren()` function in several of my searches but I don't have this function in either of my entity definition files.

What I want is to get all of the entities populated so that when I display them I can use the parents as headers and the children under the parents something like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your relations are wrong, try this instead:

```
/**
 * @var TblXchangecategories
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TblXchangecategories")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hier_parent", referencedColumnName="id")
 * 
 */
private $hierParent;

/**
 * @var TblXchangecategories
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TblXchangecategories", mappedBy="hierParent")
 */
private $hierChildren;
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help, when I dump the entity array all of the parent and children are still null.

Comment: have you tried to handle this process with just one entity? I'm not sure you need two entities to reach what are you trying to do. Probably there something wrong with `tblxchangecategories` entity file. The code i posted is the right way to build a self-recerencing relationship (it is also they way i did it in my application and it is working)

Comment: I'm lost I'm afraid. You'll have to explain things in more detail.

Comment: Ok, no problem, but you have to help me as well. Are you trying to reach a self-referencing relationship right? And the goal is to rappresent the categories as are rapresented in the screenshot?

Comment: Yes you are correct. However I still need two tables because some children have multiple parents... and typing that last sentence made me realize I need a many to many (oops, I'll change the relationships). Back to my thought if we see the pic 'Everything Else' is child to multiple parents. On certain parents though the paid field is true which is why the join table has that field.

Comment: i strongly recommend to treat "Everything else" as two different records, i mean to add it twice in your database as two different children

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49759/discussion-between-john-the-ripper-and-ponciste)

Answer (score 0):

I think if it's posible. You could use existing tree behaviors, they have a lot of useful methods for manage your hierachy. [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) or [DoctrineBehaviors](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors) from knplabs.